# Tracking depth in a non-recursive breadth first search

Tags: language-agnostic, tree, breadth-first-search

I have the following algorithm for a breadth first search:

```
q := []
q.append(root node of tree)
while q:
    n := q.pop(0)
    yield n
        if n has children:
            c := children of node
            for i in c:
                q.append(i)
```

1) How could this be extended so it keeps track of the current depth?
2) Would this extension apply to a similar algorithm for depth first search, with the queue `q` replaced by a stack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just store the depth with the nodes and increment it every time you generate a node's children.

```
q := [(root, 0)]
while q:
    n, depth := q.pop()
    yield n, depth
    if n has children:
        c := children of n
        for i in c:
            q.append(i, depth + 1)
```

This idea extends to DFS and heuristic-guided search.

Comment: perfect save me for long time of debugging

Answer (score 1):

To expand on larsmans' excellent answer, below is my [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code for depth-limited breadth-first binary tree traversal.

(The code assumes that Node does not include depth information, and wraps each node in a NodeAndDepth structure before enqueueing it.)

```c
struct NodeAndDepth {
    NodeAndDepth(Node *n, unsigned int d) : node(n), depth(d) {}
    Node *node;
    unsigned int depth;
};

void traverseBreadthFirst_WithDepthLimit(Node *root, unsigned int maxDepth) {
    if (maxDepth == 0 || root == NULL) { return; }

    std::queue<NodeAndDepth> q;
    q.push(NodeAndDepth(root, 1));

    while (!q.empty()) {
        NodeAndDepth n = q.front(); q.pop();

        // visit(n.node); 
        // cout << n.depth << ": " << n.node->payload << endl;

        if (n.depth >= maxDepth) { continue; }

        if (n.node->left != NULL) {
            q.push(NodeAndDepth(n.node->left, n.depth + 1));
        }

        if (n.node->right != NULL) {
            q.push(NodeAndDepth(n.node->right, n.depth + 1));
        }
    }
}
```